# css lost when move file one folder deep

Tags: css

My pages in pretty basic html hold styling when kept in the root folder. Created a new folder for a group, but when I move pages to that folder they seem to lose connection to the css file.

Thought the problem might be the link since it now had to move up one folder. So I changed this:

```
link href="assets/css/readable/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"
```

To this:

```
link href="http://www.example.com/assets/css/readable/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"
```

but that changed nothing. Still page works fine in root folder, but not in /new folder.

Thank you for pointing out the basic premise I could be missing.

Comment: you probably should be using root-relative paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`link href="/assets/css/readable/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"`

Add a `/` at the beginning of the path to refer to the Document Root instead of using a relative path.

Comment: Wow, smh. Thought I accomplished that by going with the full url. Clearly your answer fixed it right away. Thank you.

Comment: Its a similar idea, but your need the full **path** not **url**